# Changing value of button using typescript

Tags: typescript

I'm currently trying to make my button (which says "Add to Favorites) change to "Remove from Favorites" once it's clicked. I've tried a lot of the solutions on this site (for both java and textscript), but nothing seems to be working.

My code:

```
button(id='addToFav', onclick='addToFavorites()') Add to Favorites
script.
  function addToFavorites(){
  var x = document.getElementById("addToFav").value;
  if (x=="Add to Favorites") {
      x = "Remove from Favorites";
  } else {
      x = "Add to Favorites";
  }
  }
```

Thank you for the help!

Comment: Does my solution work for you?

Comment: It actually didn't haha. Thanks for taking the time to answer though!

(I did manage to get it to work through other means :) )

Answer (score 2):

The question is already older, but just to give a solution by using TypeScript and Angular2.
You can use ngOnInit on your class like this and change the innerText value afterwards to the required string value.

```
import {  OnInit } from '@angular/core';
export class SomeClass implements OnInit  {
     ngOnInit() {
        console.log("ngOnInit");
        var x = document.getElementById("addToFav").innerText;
        if (x=="Add to Favorites") {
            document.getElementById("addToFav").innerText  = "Remove from Favorites";
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById("addToFav").innerText  = "Add to Favorites";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assigning the new text to "x" will not update the button text. So assign it like this.

```
 function addToFavorites(){
  var x = document.getElementById("addToFav").value;
  if (x=="Add to Favorite") {
      document.getElementById("addToFav").value = "Remove from Favorite";
  } else {
      document.getElementById("addToFav").value = "Add to Favorite";
  }
}
```

Comment: it's still not changing... it seems like the "document.getElementById("addToFav").value = "text" " isn't working.

Comment: @AnnieChen, please provide button method script.. A Plunkr url would be good

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple script that changes the value:

```
<button id="addToFav" onclick="addToFavorites();" value="1">Add to Favorites</button>

<script>
function addToFavorites() {
  var el = document.getElementById("addToFav");
  if (el.textContent == "Add to Favorites") {
      el.textContent = "Remove from Favorites";
  } else {
      el.textContent = "Add to Favorites";
  }
}
</script>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/daa5tn02/

Hopefully, you can adapt it to your code.

Answer (score 0):

Using this

```
if (obj.x =="something") {
      document.getElementById("BtnId").value = "Remove from Favorite";
  } else {
      document.getElementById("BtnId").value = "Add to Favorite";
  }
```